# Video processing / playback with alpha channel in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, ffmpeg, video-processing

### WHAT I'M AFTER

I've been exploring the best ways to do this, but seem to keep running into hiccups when trying to playback video and then grab the frame with an alpha channel (ARGB) to then be further manipulated.

I've gotten everything to work with `AForge` to then find out that the Alpha gets stripped out during the process. I considered `OpenCV`, but the `Emgu CV` has a different license that I can't use and I can't verify that `OpenCV` can read Alpha channels as well.

I looked into `FFMPEG .NET wrappers`, but haven't found any that are out of their alpha phase or have a license I can use them with (since this could be used for commercial purposes and can't be open sourced)

So I'm looking for a library that is preferably C# or C++ that can play a .MOV or .AVI while preserving it's alpha channel when I make it into a `Bitmap`.

### SUMMARY [TL;DR]

I'm looking for library / sample code

- Written preferably in C#, C++ as a fallback. Hopefully easy enough to use.
- Can playback `AVI` and `MOV` files
- Will preserve the alpha channel
- Will allow me to access each frame's ARGB values directly
- Preferably something that uses the `FFMPEG library` since it's able to read most formats I need